# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

In my Ticket.php when I create something from CRUD, I want it to get the current time in the Timezone. But I'm getting an error "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string" I've used TIMESTAMP in my db time_start

I've done this so far:

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Ticket();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
    //  $employeeIDs = ArrayHelper::map(Employee::find()->all(), 'id', 'emp_name');

        $my_date = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila'));
        $model->time_start = $my_date;
        $model->status = ('On Going');
    //  $model->employee_respond_id = array_rand($employeeIDs);
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your "create" view file look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should format $my_date when assigning to $model->time_start, because in this way you are assigning a DateTime Object to a primitive member. For example:

```
$model->time_start = $my_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```